# ElasticBeanstalk Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to develop an elastic beanstalk client interface to connect through it to my amazon account elasticbeanstalk.  I used my account's credentials from the script file `credentials.Csl`.  I signed up to my account from Google chrome but I'm getting errors. Here is my code.

```java
package PFE;


import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.AWSElasticBeanstalk;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.AWSElasticBeanstalkClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.CheckDNSAvailabilityResult;

public class Sample {

    static AWSElasticBeanstalk      eb;

    private static void init()throws Exception{


 /*
  * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [default]
  * credential profile by reading from the credentials file located at
  * (~/.aws/credentials).
  */
    AWSCredentials credentials = null;

    try {

        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
             "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
             "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
             "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
             e);
    }

    eb = new AWSElasticBeanstalkClient(credentials);
    Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
    eb.setRegion(usWest2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    init();    
    try {            
        CheckDNSAvailabilityResult c= eb.checkDNSAvailability(null);

        System.out.println("You have access to " + c.getAvailable() +
                           " Availability Zones.")

        eb.createStorageLocation();

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught Exception: " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Reponse Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("Error Code: " + ase.getErrorCode());
       System.out.println("Request ID: " + ase.getRequestId());
    }                  
}

}
```

Here are the errors that I got when running my project

```java
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<clinit>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:62) at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:106)
at PFE.Sample.init(Sample.java:29)
at PFE.Sample.main(Sample.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I thought the problem is with the `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` library so I downloaded it and added it to my referenced libraries but I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while trying to make a SQS sample... My solution is: Don't add AWS SDK for Java as as an external jar

[image: Don't]

But as a library.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for **NetBeans IDE**:

1. Download "SDK for Java" from [this](http://aws.amazon.com/ru/sdk-for-java/) page
2. Extract all files from archive for example in folder /aws-java-sdk-1.9.22
3. Copy next files to your project:

   - /aws-java-sdk-1.9.22/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.9.22.jar
   - All *.jar files from folder: /aws-java-sdk-1.9.22/third-party/
4. Now, just add all *.jar files to your project in NetBeans IDE.
5. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there are other missing libraries, so i installed the toolkit AWS for my Eclipse Kepler , with all necessary libraries.
http://aws.amazon.com/fr/eclipse/ ..link for download.